# How I can Implement Like Unlike functionality on click of image in react-native?

Tags: react-native

When I am going to click on image then only one time image is changed after click on it I am not able to change image .

So I want to know how I can achieve this functionality like unlike in react-native.I am new in react-native so please help me how I can achieve this functionality.Thank you in advanced.

[image]

Here is some code for easy to understand

```
selectLike = (type) => {
        if(type==1){
            this.setState({like:'Unlike',likeType:1})
        }
    }

 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.selectLike(1) }}>

                                       {this.state.likeType===1 ? 
                                       <View>
                                           <Image source={require('../../Images/redheart.png')} style={styles.imagetriple} />
                                        <Text style={styles.texttriple}>{this.state.like}</Text>
                                       </View>
                                       :
                                       <View>
                                           <Image source={require('../../Images/heart.png')} style={styles.imagetriple} />
                                        <Text style={styles.texttriple}>{this.state.like}</Text>
                                       </View>
                                       }

                                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this, liked is `true or false`

```
state = {
    like: 'Unlike',
    liked: false
}
    selectLike = () => {
    this.setState(prevstate => {
        return {
        ...prevstate, 
        like: (prevstate.liked ? 'Unlike' : 'like'), liked: !prevstate.liked
    }
})
}

}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectLike}>
    {this.state.liked ?
        <View>
            <Image source={
                require('../../Images/redheart.png')
            } style={
                    styles.imagetriple
                }
            /> <Text style={
                styles.texttriple
            } > {this.state.like} </Text> </View> :
        <View>
            <Image source={
                    require('../../Images/heart.png')
                } style={
                    styles.imagetriple
                }
            /> <Text style={
                    styles.texttriple
                }> {
                    this.state.like
                } </Text> </View>
    }

    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thank you @Manikandan Velayutham